# I can't personalise my error pages -- Apache ErrorDocument directive results in additional not found error

Tags: apache2, 404, error

I use apache 2.4.10, and I can't use personal error pages.

I changed `/etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf` and added :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

and created the file `/var/www/404.html` with the short string `404test` inside.

However, when I relaunch apache, I get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What's wrong?
Is there a way to get more detail on the error?

Comment: `/var/www/` is your document root? Because that's where it'll look for the document

Answer (score 1):

Roll back your changes in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf`, then use `.htaccess` to create a custom 404 page with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

If that fails then try adding the full path to the `404.html` document.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use .htaccess it add extra useless disk access.

Edit your web site configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{yoursite}.conf` add this outside any tag

```
# Error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm

# allow errors pages to be visible from any virtual host
Alias /404.htm /var/www/errors/404.htm
```

Like that your error pages will be available for any of your virtual host, without adding extra code in virtual host and save harddrive useless access.

Answer (score -1):

Using internet explorer?
your 404 page should have a minimum 0f 512 bytes of text. So say a line or 10.
just try it with longer text.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly be the problem.   He is getting a very specific message from Apache that the 404 document was not found.